# I want to show Photo in React.js project

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

The frontend is React, and the backend is DRF.
The following error message occurred while implementing a page that can display a list of posts that a logged-in user has liked.

This is the data structure of the attached photo DRF
When I add the Base-URL "http://127.0.0.1:8000/" here
I thought I could show pictures from the DRF
I get a error, but I don't know the correct one...

```
SyntaxError: /Users/hogehoge/Desktop/my_project_app/my_project_frontend/src/components/LikedPostsListPage.js: Unexpected token (63:52)

  61 |                   <p>User: {item.username}</p>
  62 |                   <p>Shipping price: {item.shipping_price}</p>
> 63 |                   <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/"{item.photo} />
```

React.js

```
  return (
      <div className="">
            <div>
              {post.map(item => (
                <div>
                  <p>Title: {item.title}</p>
                  <p>Condition: {item.condition_name}</p>
                  <p>Maker: {item.maker}</p>
                  <p>Price: {item.price}</p>
                  <p>Description: {item.description}</p>
                  <p>User: {item.username}</p>
                  <p>Shipping price: {item.shipping_price}</p>
                  <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/"{item.photo} />
                  <img src={item.photo2} />
                  <img src={item.photo3} />
                  <img src={item.photo4} />
                  <img src={item.photo5} />
                  <Link to={`/post/${item.id}`} className='btn btn-secondary'>Detail</Link>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
```

DRF

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.UpdateOwnProfile,)
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @action(detail=False, permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated])
    def liked_posts(self, request, pk=None):
        liked_posts = request.user.like_by_user.all()
        post_data = []
        for i in range(len(liked_posts)):
            post_data.append(liked_posts[i].post)
        data = PostSerializer(post_data,many=True).data
        return Response(data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I can't show the photo....

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error. Fix it to:

```
src={`http://127.0.0.1:8000/${item.photo}`}
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Thank you. <img src={`http://127.0.0.1:8000${item.photo}`} /> works!